# Make ng-view display only its contents, not itself

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am working on a small AngularJS blogging app (the framework version I use is 1.7.8).

I also use an HTML template that I did *not* do myself, I prefer to make very few changes to it *if any*.

Keeping the following HTML structure is important because of the CSS that styles it:

```css
#main {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#main>.inner {
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<section id="main">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>Ad eum nibh mutat porro, sit no minimum dissentias, ceteros explicari persecuti sea ei.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

**The problem:**

I display the views with the help of routing:

```
angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute',
    'app.controllers'
]).config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/posts.html',
        controller: 'PostsController'
    }).when('/post/:slug', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/singlepost.html',
        controller: 'SinglePostController'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
}]);
```

This requires an `<ng-view></ng-view>` block in my index.html file. This, of course, makes a big part of the CSS useless, as can be seen below:

```css
#main {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#main>.inner {
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<section id="main">
  <ng-view>
    <div class="inner">
      <p>Ad eum nibh mutat porro, sit no minimum dissentias, ceteros explicari persecuti sea ei.</p>
    </div>
  </ng-view>
</section>
```

**Note:** I know that replacing `#main>.inner` with `#main .inner` would solve the styling problem described above, but the snippet is just an example that helps me make a point (demonstration). I need a solution that does not requre changing the CSS.

Is there a way to make ng-view display **only its inner HTML**, and not itself?

Comment: I think the only workaround is to create custom directive with `replace: true` that will wrap `ng-view` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25353822/is-it-possible-to-set-ng-view-to-replace-true

Comment: The `<ng-view>` needs to stay in order for it to be available for all routes. You will need to modify something...structure or css

Comment: how about you use the `ng-view` as an attribute ? `<section id="main" ng-view>` as described [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you use the `ng-view` directive as an attribute ?

```css
#main {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#main>.inner {
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<section id="main" ng-view>
    <div class="inner">
      <p>Ad eum nibh mutat porro, sit no minimum dissentias, ceteros explicari persecuti sea ei.</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-view Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView)